# Can the condition of a requires-clause be of type implicitly convertible to bool?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, requires-clause

In the following example the requires-expression of second `f`-function overload has the type `std::integral_constant<bool,true>`, which is implicitly convertible to `bool`:

```
#include <type_traits>

struct S {
    static constexpr bool valid = true;
};

template<typename T>
int f() { return 1; }
template<typename T>
int f() requires( std::bool_constant< T::valid >() ) { return 2; }

int main() {
    return f<S>();
}
```

One can observe that GCC rejects the program due to the type is not precisely `bool`, but Clang accepts, but selects the other overload `int f() { return 1; }`. Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/nf65zrxoK

Which compiler is correct here?

Comment: I did not find anything which sasy that any expression will be implicitly converted to bool. As this, gcc looks ok for me. To get an explicit conversion to bool you have to write: `std::bool_constant< T::valid >::value` or do an explicit cast like `(bool)std::bool_constant< T::valid >`. If you want to call the execution operator, you have to create an object before: `std::bool_constant< T::valid >{}()`. Is it only a typo in your code that you forget the object creation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe GCC is correct—the type must be `bool` exactly per [[temp.constr.atomic]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.constr.constr#temp.constr.atomic-3) (note that `E` here is `std::bool_constant< T::valid >()`):

> To determine if an atomic constraint is satisfied, the parameter mapping and template arguments are first substituted into its expression. If substitution results in an invalid type or expression, the constraint is not satisfied. Otherwise, the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is performed if necessary, **and E shall be a constant expression of type bool**. The constraint is satisfied if and only if evaluation of E results in true. If, at different points in the program, the satisfaction result is different for identical atomic constraints and template arguments, the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required. [ Example:
>
> ```
> template<typename T> concept C =
>   sizeof(T) == 4 && !true;      // requires atomic constraints sizeof(T) == 4 and !true
>
> template<typename T> struct S {
>   constexpr operator bool() const { return true; }
> };
>
> template<typename T> requires (S<T>{})
> void f(T);                      // #1
> void f(int);                    // #2
>
> void g() {
>   f(0);                         // error: expression S<int>{} does not have type bool
> }                               // while checking satisfaction of deduced arguments of #1;
>                                 // call is ill-formed even though #2 is a better match
> ```
>
> — end example ]